# React json list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I hope I can explain the question clearly. I need to create a few categories in category with `<input type="checkbox"/>`. Can you help how do it

```
{
  "properties":{

    "category":[
       "0" : "category-1",
       "1" : "category-2"
    ],
    "image": "https://link...",
    ...
 }
}
```

now I can only add one value at a time, but I need a lot

```
{
      "properties":{

        "category": "category-1",
        "image": "https://link...",
        ...
     }
    }




 const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
            e.preventDefault();
    
            const movie = {id, category, title, poster, rating, year, video, trailer, description};
    
            fetch('http://localhost:8000/movies', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {"Content-Type" : "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify(movie)
            }).then(() => {
                alert('Успешно добавился фильм!');
            })
        }
```

Comment: Could you please update question with React related code? Instead of posting single `category` replace it with `categories` and provide list of selected categories. Than apply changes on backend side - so, it could handle request like that

Answer (score 0):

So if im understanding you correctly, you want to add multiple categories to the body of a POST endpoint? As long as your api handles an array for the “category”, then its pretty easy! But first, there are some things I see in your code:

1. In javascript, you don’t explicitly write the index of an array. You just write the item, for
   example

```
 const listOfStrings = [“string 1”, “string 2”] 

const listOfObj = [{name: ‘Aj”}, {name: ‘bj’}]
```

2. It seems like you are implicitly passing in the properties for your “movie” object, just make sure that each property is defined somewhere above.

Now on to your question! What you want to do is the following:

1. Create a list of categories, make sure they match whatever the backend is expecting
2. create a state to track the selected categories
3. map through the array and render an input for each
4. assign each input props based on its indexed category
5. create a function that updates the selected state with a new category or a category removed

The key principles you'll need to research if youre unfamiliar with this are:

- Javascript: [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- React: [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html),
  [Rendering lists](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)
  [hooks (useState)](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Code Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-moon-fbhs7c?file=/src/App.js